# how to sort a directory as needed

Tags: macos, unix

The problem is i have a directory that contains 10 files, from chapter 1 to chapter 10. And i know unix sort files in alphabetical order by default, but the thing is those files list like this: chapter 1, chapter 10, chapter 2 ...

chapter 10 becomes the 2nd one since it starts with a 1.

their size is random so sort by size doesn't work)

```
$ ls
chapter1  chapter10 chapter2  chapter3  chapter5  chapter6  chapter7  chapter8  chapter9
```

This drives me crazy for no reason, i have to move it to last.
Is there any command i can use (mac os)?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your output to sort command

> ls | sort -tr -k2 -n

**Sort command line options** : 
-tr means using 'r' as a field separator character
-k2 means using second column as sort key
So you can sort according to the numeric part.

At last, you need -n to sort fields numerically by arithmetic value
You can check sort man page for more detail.

Comment: It works, but i can't type ls | sort -tr -k2 -n every time when i need to use ls command tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `ls -v`

from ls man :

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: The -v switch has a different meaning on macOS.